# Algorithm to convert any string to a 1-3 digit number

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I want to make an algorithm, for a NodeJS app, that converta any given string to a 1 to 3 digit number (better if the number is between 1-500).

```
e.g
ExampleString -> 214
```

Can anyone help me find a good solution?

**EDIT:**
I want to get a [crime coefficient](http://psychopass.wikia.com/wiki/Crime_Coefficient_(Index)) number from a username (string).

Comment: return 1 seems to be valid

Comment: How should we know how to convert the strings? What's on your mind? What have you tried?

Comment: So there are only 500 strings possible?

Comment: You have to give us some clue what problem you're actually trying to use this for so we know how to best go about it.  Without the limitation of 1-500, we could just calculate a hash of the characters in the string.  But, with that limitation, it's not clear what you actually want or care about.  Heck, we could just return a random number and be done with the info you've given us about requirements.

Comment: how do you get `'214'`?

Comment: Google "string hashing algorithm".

Comment: I don't require it to be unique.

Comment: Do you mean random?

Comment: I'm actually making a algorithm to get a crime coefficient from a user name.

Comment: **DO YOU MEAN RANDOM?** Randomly get a number between 1 and 500 that only contains 1 - 3 digits?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes.

Comment: @NinaScholz That's just an example guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you can use JS function to get charCode of letter

```
let str = "some string example";
let sum = 0;
for (let i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
  sum += parseInt(str[i].charCodeAt(0), 10); // Sum all codes
}

// Now we have some value as Number in sum, lets convert it to 0..1 value to scale to needed value
let rangedSum = parseFloat('0.' + String(sum)); // Looks dirty but works
let resultValue = Math.round(rangedSum * 500) + 1; // Same alogorythm as using Math.random(Math.round() * (max-min)) + min;
```

I hope it helps.

So as you are using nodejs, you can use **crypto** library to get md5 hash of string and then get it as HEX.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
let valueHex = crypto.createHash('md5').update('YOUR STRING HERE').digest('hex');
// then get it as decimal based value
let valueDec = parseInt(valueHex, 16);
// and apply the same algorythm as above to scale it between 1-500
```

Comment: This works fine, for whatever I've tested till now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: And you need to change
`i <= str.length` to `i < str.length` in the for loop

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for that error in loop. Already fixed

Answer (score 0):

```js
function coeficient() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 500) + 1;
}

console.log(coeficient());
console.log(coeficient());
console.log(coeficient());
```

Comment: THis just generates a random 3 digit number. Thanks but not exactly what I want. @p1ratRulezZZ answer looks promising.